# Examples of complex manifolds with trivial Néron–Severi group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors

$\DeclareMathOperator\NS{NS}\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}$Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, assume projective if you'd like. Define the Néron–Severi group to be the quotient $$\NS(X) = \Pic(X) / \Pic^0(X).$$ Suppose that $\Pic(X) = \Pic^0(X) \neq 0$. So all divisors are algebraically equivalent, and (by definition) the Picard number is zero.

Can we infer any geometric information from this constraint (does this constrain other invariants such as Kodaira dimension, curvature, etc.)? Are there examples of such $X$? Are there plenty of such examples?

Comment: For projective varieties this means it is a point.

Comment: A classical example is the [Hopf surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface) $X$, for which $\operatorname{Pic}(X)=\operatorname{Pic}^{0}(X)=\mathbb{C}^*  $.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you! Is this obvious, do you have a reference, or can indicate the idea?

Comment: @abx Thank you for this, are there Kähler examples?

Comment: If $L$ is an ample line bundle, it is not algebraically equivalent to zero.

Comment: @Mohan Of course! Thank you!

Comment: In fact $X$ (if not a point) cannot be algebraic: assume $U\subset X$ is a nonempty affine open subset. Then $Y:=X\smallsetminus U$ (with reduced structure) is a divisor. On the other hand $U$ contains an affine irreducible curve $C$. Its closure $\overline{C}$ satisfies $\overline{C}.Y>0$, so $Y$ cannot be algebraically trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Kähler example constructed in [1, Section 1].

Let $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ be a lattice, $\phi: \Gamma \to \Gamma$ a $\mathbb{Z} $-linear map with characteristic polynomial $f(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda - \lambda_i)(\lambda - \overline{\lambda_i}) $ where $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n,\overline{\lambda_1},\cdots,\overline{\lambda_n}$ are distinct non-real complex numbers. Then $\Gamma_\mathbb{C}=\Gamma \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{C}$ has decomposition $\Gamma_\mathbb{C} = \Gamma' \oplus \overline{\Gamma'}$ where $\Gamma'$ is the eigenspace of eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\}$. Then we have a complex torus $T=\Gamma_\mathbb{C}/\Gamma'\oplus \Gamma$ of complex dimension $n$. And [1] proved that,for $n\ge2$, if the Galois group of $f$ is the $2n$-th symmetric group, then ${\rm NS}(T)=0$.

[1] C. Voisin. On the homotopy types of compact Kähler and complex projective manifolds, Inventiones Math. Volume 157, Number 2, 329 - 343.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Is it clear that $\operatorname{Pic}(T) \neq 0?$

Comment: @ Francesco Polizzi Yes, in this case ${\rm Pic}(T)={\rm Pic}^0(T)$ is the dual torus of $T$. So it does not vanish.